# Fetching a document by its URL via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, domdocument

I'm trying to fetch an HTML document object, not the text of the page, given its URL, via Javascript. The reason I need the Document object is so I can look for a given classname and take a certain action if it exists.

Comment: is the other document located on a different domain ?

Answer (score 1):

If the page is in the same domain (i.e. a relative path) you could load it inside a hidden iframe, and access the `document` from `window.frames` as shown [here](http://xkr.us/articles/dom/iframe-document/)

Comment: No, you can't access an iframe from another domain, unless they cooperate and use particular techniques. See http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Answer (score 0):

```
function saveDataToVariable(data) {
    var html = data;
    // do something
}

$.get('any.html', saveDataToVariable);
```

this will give you the complete html output of a given html page... also including the html or div tags an anything else will be included and you can parse it afterwards as you need

Comment: Actually, the page is part of Google Groups, which is not my domain. I'm writing a Chrome extension that searches for posts whose subject lines contain a given character string. From the browser, using the search query "subject:<some data>", I get the search results. I just want to do the same thing programmatically. I know how to format the URL, but not how to retrieve the page, except as text which doesn't help, since it's obfuscated (I'm looking for a particular classname and if it's there, I do one thing; if not, I do another). That's why I need a Document returned.

Comment: How do I implement this, Mik? When I run it, I get an exception: Uncaught reference error: $ is not defined. It doesn't seem to be valid Javascript.

Comment: Never mind. It seems that $.get() is a php function that's equivalent to extracting the HTML data string via XMLHttpRequest()...which I already tried and which returns raw obfuscated data that I can't analyze.

Comment: sorry..was off for some days... use jQuery instead of $ ... you can just use $ if it was referenced before ... most people do this right at the beginning thats why yuo mostly see $